# VMWare Virtual Machines Black Console/APIPA

Tags: networking, vmware-vcenter, vmware-tools

We seem to have some strange issues in our environment and haven't had great luck finding a root cause to the issue. So the problem typically lies when we upgrade systems (sometimes this happens overnight at random during our scheduled machine reboots too). Once the machine completes it's configuration (or reboots at night), it is assigned an APIPA address (see image) and the console then shows up black indefinitely. [APIPAADDRESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16bIr.png)

The console is still interactive, as far as being able to see the mouse cursor within the window but everything is black and you are not able to click anything.

Per a comment, apologies for forgetting to include, these are Windows 7 machines that this happens to. We don't typically have servers or other OS's reboot (as we don't use anything other than Windows 7 for our end users. We're running about 300+ Windows 7 user VMs. We do have a number of server 2008-2016 but again when we do reboot them, it goes fine but technically sort of a different environment per se) so I can't speak as to if that would happen to them as well.

What we've tried to resolve it:

1. Rebuild the machine using the layering technology (reassembles the registry, re-installs applications, re-attaches drives, etc). No effect unfortunately.
2. Remove the network adapter, re-attach it. No effect either.
3. Migrate the machine to another host in the same cluster. No effect.
4. Move the adapter to another distributed switch within the cluster. No effect.

This is quite the head scratcher for us and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these all Windows servers? Can you provide OS details?

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to include, updated the question. I know it's for Windows 7 but it's in a server environment (ESXI 6.0)/an engineering issue/administration issue so I thought this was appropriate, if not let me know and I'll take my question to the appropriate area. :)

Comment: When you say this happens when you upgrade systems, what do you mean? What's being upgraded? If you're upgrading the hosts are you making sure that the VMware Tools on the guests is being upgraded as well?

Comment: We aren't upgrading the hosts themselves, we are upgrading the guests within the host (e.g. Windows 7). We use a layering technology called Unidesk that enables us to layer the applications (it attaches new virtual disks for each application layer) but that doesn't appear to be the problem in it's entirety as it happens at random too to one or two machines. We did notice the tools were out of date so we updated it on a several and unfortunately one still failed on us.